# Deserialing Guava class with custom comparator using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, guava, fasterxml

I am using Guava TreeMultiset in one of my classes for a field that needs to be serialized/deserialized into a sorted multiset. I am using a custom comparator to construct the TreeMultiset:

```
private SortedMultiset<UserFavCatsNode> ms = TreeMultiset.create(new customComparator());
```

Serialization seems to be working fine, but deserialization fails as Jackson does not have access to the custom comparator to construct a TreeMuliset instance. How do **I pass the comparator instance while deserializing?**

I initially searched and found two options:

1. Implement the Comparable interface. This works, but imposing custom ordering on the class itself is unsatisfactory.
2. I tried to get around by writing a wrapper class based on a post (http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/de-serialize-treeset-by-first-defining-a-comparator), and calling this using the @JsonDeserialize annotation

`public Constructor(@JsonDeserialize(as = CustomTreeMultiset.class) field) {
//
}`

This strategy fails because **Guava TreeMultiset is final** and I cannot implement CustomTreeMultiset that extends it to provide a wrapper deserialization class. Is there a better solution than infuse custom ordering logic into the class?

Comment: No idea about Jackson, but in general, you hardly ever *must* subclass anything. So try a `ForwardingMultiset` with your own strategy.

Comment: Did you find a solution?